# Angular : how to access HTML tag Class in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access the class names of Form and its controls in the Typescript file.
Is it possible?
Please check the Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ps9aeb

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.ModelForm.form.controls.firstName?.valid);
  }
```

The above  code is giving error

```
Error in src/app/app.component.ts (11:22)
Property 'ModelForm' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

Comment: If you want to check individual control validation, you should use ReactiveForms instead of TemplateForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@ViewChild` to have access to the template driven form in your typescript file.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('ModelForm') 
  public ModelForm: NgForm;
  //...
}
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypsta6